# Get specific values from array?

Tags: php, arrays, steam

I have found some code to get some information of steam gameservers. They query the server like this:

$Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

```
    print_r( $Query->GetInfo( ) );
    print_r( $Query->GetPlayers( ) );
    print_r( $Query->GetRules( ) );
```

and the outfit will be like:

```
Array
(
    [Protocol] => 17
    [HostName] => Bla
    [Map] => TheIsland
    [ModDir] => BlaBlaBla
    [ModDesc] => BlaBlaBla
    [AppID] => 0
    [Players] => 5
    [MaxPlayers] => 70
    [Bots] => 0
    [Dedicated] => d
    [Os] => w
    [Password] => 1
    [Secure] => 1
    [Version] => 1.0.0.0
    [ExtraDataFlags] => 177
    [GamePort] => 27016
    [ServerID] => etc
    [GameTags] => ,OWNINGID:90096846886881289,OWNINGNAME:90096846886881289,NUMOPENPUBCONN:65,P2PADDR:90096846886881289,P2PPORT:27016,ModId_l:0
    [GameID] => 346110
)
```

But how can I use php to get a single value and echo it ? Like "MAP" I want to echo ?

Thank you

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Comment: Probably something like: `$array = $Query->GetInfo( ); echo $array['Map'];` Unless there is something I am missing...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on php version. You can use next construction:

```
echo $Query->GetInfo()['Map'];
```

or next code will work for all versions :)

```
$qwe = $Query->GetInfo();
echo $qwe['Map'];
```

Comment: Thank you !! The first one caused a PHP error (unexpected "[") but second one was working! Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to echo only Map from array.

```
$mainArray =  $Query->GetInfo( );

echo $mainArray['Map'];
```